# How to syncronize two google calendars from two different accounts

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I use Google Calendar API to syncronize my Google Calendars with my website calendar. Is it posible to syncronize to different calendars from two different accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that calendar data is private user data.  In order to access a calendar your going to have to be logged in as the user who owns the calendar. So to synchronize these calendars using the api. You are going to need to be authenticated and logged in to both of the accounts at the same time.

My knowledge of the Google api JavaScript client library is very limited.  I am not sure how it would be able to handle two logins at the same time.  My understanding would be that you would only have one login working at a time.  So you would have to store the data someplace then have the user login to the second account and upload it.   Javascript being a client sided language would make this very difficult IMO.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I have to be logged in to both of the accounts. I'm interesting does Google allow to do that.

Comment: I could do it with C# or php.   I just dont think you could do it with JavaScript.  But like i said my JavaScript knowledge is limited. I am not sure how the login works.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, If it works with php, I will try to do with javascript.